# update iterm2 title with SSH User & Hostname

Tags: iterm

How can I get iTerm2 to update the title of each tab with the User & Hostname of the remote SSH host? currently the best I can achieve is “ssh user@hostname” and with multiple tabs this makes it impossible to differentiate between them as it gets to the point where only the “ssh” part is visible

Answer (score 1):

You don't.

Instead you get the remote to update the title of the window.  This is usually done in the shell prompt configuration on the remote.  You also configure the local to set the window title, so that when the `ssh` session ends, the title is not set to the remote any longer.

Here's an example:

```
# xterm titlebar

TITLEBAR=$(printf '\033]0;')
BELL=$(printf '\007')

# set prompt

case $TERM in
    # xterm and variants, set the titlebar
    xterm*) PS1='${TITLEBAR}[\u@\h]${BELL}\h \$ ' ;;                                                                    

    # anything else, don't try to set the titlebar
    *) PS1='\u@\h \$ ' ;;                                                                                         
esac
```

[image: terminal.app]

The TITLEBAR escape code tells the terminal the shell is running in that it should set the titlebar to the text that follows.  You end the string with a BELL.

The `case` statement is a simplistic test for whether or not the terminal the shell is running in is an Xterm or compatible.

The particular backslash escapes your shell supports for prompt information (hostname, username, the time, etc) are spelled out in its documentation.

You may find the [BASH Prompt HowTo](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/) useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with its [Shell Integration feature](https://iterm2.com/documentation-shell-integration.html). Just run the following command on the machine you ssh from and to and it should work automatically if you use tcsh, zsh, bash, and fish 2.3 or later:

```sh
curl -L https://iterm2.com/shell_integration/install_shell_integration.sh | bash
```